# JQuery function affecting ALL elements of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a script to toggle (on click) a class between elements of a group (slide-container) that works well.
Since I have multiple containers with the same class, all elements are affected.
I need to target only the clicked elements belonging to this slide-container. Not other slide-container

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function activeSlide() {
    $("a.slide.active").not(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  }

  $("a.slide").on("click", activeSlide);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Test custom slider</h1>
  <div class="slide-container">
    <a href="#" class="slide active">
      <img src="patio-estrie-1.jpeg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="slide">
      <img src="patio-estrie-2.jpeg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="slide">
      <img src="patio-estrie-1.jpeg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="slide">
      <img src="patio-estrie-2.jpeg" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-container">
    <a href="#" class="slide active">
      <img src="patio-estrie-1.jpeg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="slide">
      <img src="patio-estrie-2.jpeg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="slide">
      <img src="patio-estrie-1.jpeg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="slide">
      <img src="patio-estrie-2.jpeg" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet - please add the relevant CSS so we can see the issue within the snippet itself.  See [mcve].

Comment: From the code provided, you *probably* want: `$(this).closest(".slide-container").find("a.slide.active").not(this)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("a.slide.active").not(this).removeClass("active");
```

you can find the `.slide` elements in the current container:

```
$(this).closest(".slide-container").find("a.slide").removeClass("active");
```

That will only affect the relevant container. Then, instead of `.toggleClass()`, you can use `.addClass()` because you know that the current clicked element is the one to be active:

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

If the intention is to allow an "active" element to be deactivated, so that all of them can be deactivated, then your own logic can be adapted to that. The key is the `.closest()` to find the container.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $("a.slide").click(function(){
    let id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $("#"+id+" a.slide.active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Test custom slider</h1>
      <div class="slide-container" id="slide1">
        <a href="#" class="slide active">
          <img src="patio-estrie-1.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="slide">
          <img src="patio-estrie-2.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="slide">
          <img src="patio-estrie-1.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="slide">
          <img src="patio-estrie-2.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-container" id="slide2">
        <a href="#" class="slide active">
          <img src="patio-estrie-1.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="slide">
          <img src="patio-estrie-2.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="slide">
          <img src="patio-estrie-1.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="slide">
          <img src="patio-estrie-2.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You should put the id in the "Slider" divs. This way you can separate the two. and you can run it with the javascript code I added.

Comment: No need for IDs.  IDs are an anti-pattern.  Use relative DOM navigation - which you already are to *get* the ID - your code makes no sense: get parent so you can get parent's ID, so that you can get the parent by its ID??